# loop a write (out) statement in html

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to loop an out statement in javascript? Kind of like a recursive function that will just spit out whatever over and over each time it calls itself. I have a javascript line set up to loop and would like to see it output to the webpage over and over without over writing the previous output each time.

this is the write statement I am using now...

```
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=i;
```

this line only outputs to the "output" id within the page. is there a way to use this line or another command to get my continuous output?

this is for my work so I am trying to leave out the job specifics. If you need more data let me know and I will put in as much as I can.

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply append to the element's innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += i;
```

Comment: This is correct though it's probably better to use `.textContent`

Comment: is there a way to add a break tag to this output statement to put each output on its own line?

Comment: @Odin1806 `+= i+"<br />"`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can you also take a look at my other question. Maybe you might be able to shed some light there too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717111/embedding-an-unlisted-youtube-video-on-website